# Reverse string error

Tags: objective-c, c, char, reverse

I am writing reverseString function by myself. (For test use) And I use iOS platform to run my c code, which sounds weird, but again, for test use...

Here is my code:

```
-(char *) reverseString:(char *)str
{
    char *end = str;
    char tmp;

    if (str)
    {
        while (*end) { end++; }
        --end;
        NSLog(@"%c", *end);
        while (end>str)
        {
            tmp = *str;
            *str = *end;
            str++;
            *end = tmp;
            end--;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%s", str);
    return str;
}
```

After running the function by calling:

```
char *testChar = "abcd";
[self reverseString:testChar];
```

I received the error on line:

```
*str = *end;
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x2de4)
```

I don't really know understand what's wrong with the pointer here...Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What language is this? It's not ISO C!

Comment: @Dughall: It's [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) but he's trying to use it to play with C.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mixed obj-c with c. I know it's pretty ugly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify a string literal. Use a char array instead.

```
char testChar[] = "abcd";
```

Comment: Great! that's it. I really thought char* and a char array were the same thing.